# socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] when reading lists of domains

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using the following code below to read a textfile (hosts.txt) into a list and then i'm trying to resolve each one to their IP using socket.gethostbyname()

```
import socket

non_blank_count = 0

with open('hosts.txt') as infp:
    for line in infp:
        non_blank_count += 1

print 'IPs to be resolved %d' % non_blank_count     


with open('hosts.txt') as fp:
    content = fp.readlines()

i=0

while i < non_blank_count:
    print("Host: %s : IP: %s") % (content[i], socket.gethostbyname(content[i]))
    i = i+1
```

Whenever i try to do this i get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 18, in
>   
>       print("Host: %s : IP: %s") % (content[i], socket.gethostbyname(content[i])) socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004]
>   getaddrinfo failed

If I try from idle using the following it works fine:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname("google.com")
'74.125.237.99'
```

I think its got something to do with the double quotes but i'm not sure, i've tried a couple of variations and they all have the same results (including having the hosts enclosed in double quotes)

My hosts.txt file is formatted like this

```
site.com
www.site.subsite.com
im.another.site.com
etc.com
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`file.readlines`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.readlines) return list of strings without stripping newlines. You have to strip it using [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.strip)

When you process file line by line, use file as iterator instead of using `file.readlines`:

```
import socket

with open('hosts.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        host = line.strip()
        print "Host: {}  IP: {}".format(host, socket.gethostbyname(host))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the trailing '\n' from each address. Try the following:

```
content[i].rstrip('\n'), socket.gethostbyname(content[i].rstrip('\n'))
```